# UIScrollView not scrolling no matter what I try

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uiscrollview, xcode8

I have a screen where the main view has a `UIScrollView` which contains a `UIView` which in turn contains 3 `UIView`s placed vertically, I have set the constraints accordingly, trying setting `contentSize` in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, all to no avail. I have created a sample project with the issue I'm facing at https://github.com/modsoussi/ScrollViewTest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised Interface Builder isn't showing a Constraints error or warning...

When using auto-layout, the *contents* of the scroll view define the `contentSize`. That means the contents (in your case, a single `UIView` holding 3 smaller `UIView`s) must have a constraint to the Top, Leading, Trailing and Bottom of its superview (the scroll view)... **and** it must have a Height and Width.

In your storyboard, delete the "Center Vertically" constraint, and add a Height constraint (of 1000) to the "content" view. Then delete your `scrollView.contentSize = ...` line from code. Run the app, and you should have no problem scrolling.